# The import com.rti cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, rti-dds

I downloaded files from https://github.com/nasa/astrobee_gds/tree/master , which is published by NASA.

**Requirements**
JDK 1.8
Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 with modeling tools
Git
DDS Implementation (RTI DDS)

**My settings**
Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

I downloaded RTI 30-days trial version from official homepage.
When I open the file (astrobee_gds), I got so many error messages "The import com.rti cannot be resolved".
Does anyone know about this issue?

I saw lots of this problem solved by adding external .jar file.
However, I cannot find rti's jar file.

Comment: Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 is almost a decade and 26 releases behind and also the mentioned project is quite old. [One or more repositories with required dependencies no longer seem to exist](https://github.com/nasa/astrobee_gds/blob/1945c7cf63ef526efaf975137102cdc6cad4640f/gov.nasa.arc.ff.ocu.product/OCU.target). It will not work if you do not get the dependencies from somewhere else (from another repository, product or installation).